# undefined method each_pair in Rails erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `each_pair' for []:Array
```

when trying to iterate over an hash in a Rails erb view:

```
<% @result.each_pair do |k, v| %>
  <li><%= k %></li>
<% end %>
```

In plain Ruby, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: So, is result an array or a hash?

Comment: @result is a Hash (definitely, because @result.kind_of?(Hash) = true)

Comment: Well, apparently not. Or not in every case.

Answer (score 3):

According to error message, `@result` must be an **Array**. Method `each_pair` is not defined for it. (Method `each_pair` is defined for Hash or such like.)

Try this:

```
<% @result.each do |v| %>
  <li><%= v %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're both right (of course). On the initial page load I was using

```
@result = []
```

it only becomes a hash after it's been populated.

Using

```
@result = Hash.new
```

fixed everything

Sorry for the useless post